# iPhone app runs on iOS 4.3 when deployment target is 5.0 and does not run on ios 5.1 when deployment target is 4.3

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

My iPhone app runs on `iOS 4.3` ( `iPhone 3GS`) when deployment target is `5.0` and does not run on `iOS 5.1` (`iPod 4`) when the deployment target is `4.3`.

I'm confused why this is happening and I want to make sure I set the right deployment target.

I want my app to be compatible with the `iPhone 3GS` and better phones.

I have always been testing my app using the iOS 5.0 deployment target and it has always worked fine on the devices I have tested it on, however I read that it is necessary to set the deployment target as the lowest compatible iOS version, but doing so seems to do the opposite of what I would expect to happen.

I am using `cocos2d` for my app if that makes any difference.

Comment: How u can install iOS 4.3 on iPhone 4GS ? At default iOS on new iPhone 4GS, is iOS 5 and larger.

Comment: I'm confused. What's the "iPhone 4GS"?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the 3GS, I've edited the post.

Comment: What is your XCode version ? And Mac OS

Comment: For Snow Leopard is latest XCode, i think, XCode 4.3. Try update

Comment: XCode 4.2 is the latest version for snow leopard. I added support for the newer iOS targets myself.

Comment: What compile error u see when try run on iPod 4 ?

Comment: I'm not even getting an error anymore. It seems to be magically working now.

It's possible it has something to do with changing the accelerometer require device capabilities, because that's about the only thing I changed.

Answer (score 0):

Your deployment target should be set to the lowest version of iOS you want to support, in your case 4.3. But your Base SDK should be set to Latest iOS
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is more of an architecture issue it seems. Try adding armv6 architecture in addition to armv7 and armv7s.